# Invalid RFC3339 format for time data

Tags: date, go, timestamp

I've a data which I'm trying to convert to unix timestamp but I think my rfc3339 data coming from server is not proper.

```
data:='2020-07-08T01:11:02-0700'
startDate, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, data.(string))
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("err is", err)
    return
}
```

This is the error I'm getting

```
err is parsing time "2020-07-08T01:11:02-0700" as "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00": cannot parse "-0700" as "Z07:00".
```

What is a proper rfc format or how should I change my output in a way that this function could work and then I can convert this to timestamp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is in time offset format. You have `-0700` which is not compliant with RFC3339. You need to pass `-07:00`. See `time-numoffset` format in grammar [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339#section-5.6).

For time format you have you need to pass following custom layout so it parses the offset correctly:

```golang
data := "2020-07-08T01:11:02-0700"
startDate, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02T15:04:05-0700", data)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. the data is always coming in different format, so i dont' know if there's an easy way to format the last 2 digits always like this? How can i guarantee it? @blami

Comment: You can achieve that by providing custom layout that matches what service returns instead of RFC3339. I updated my answer with example.

Comment: that's much easier. Instead of using a regex or some other methods, thank you! I upvoted your answer

Comment: @curiosityrock if the answer is sufficient, please accept it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @mkopriva just did!